# Wordpress the_date() to a custom string

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to output to the WordPress UI: "On 2023-10-24 at 20:00". What's wrong?
In UI I get:

`2023-10-24 09:37On`
**`Warning`**`: Undefined array key 1 in` **`C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress_tutorial\wp-content\themes\learntocustomtheme\templates\post-page.php`**`on line`**`7`**
`at`

My code:

```
<?php
    $date_time = the_date('Y-m-d H:i');
    $date_arr = explode(" ", $date_time);
    echo ("On " . $date_arr[0]);
    echo (" at " . $date_arr[1]);
?>
```

I tried to make two variables

```
the_date('Y-m-d')
the_date('H:i');
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3783243 It's a Wordpress-specific function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_date/

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" How so? What happens when you try to use the alternative?

Comment: When you `echo` `$date_time` and `$date_arr` from the first example, what's the result?

Comment: By default, [the_date echoes the value instead of returning it](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_date/). If you want to return the value, then you need to pass `false` as the 4th parameter. You can use the defaults for the 2nd and 3rd. [get_the_date](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/) will always return the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$my_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(get_the_date('Y-m-d'));
$my_time = date('H:i:s', strtotime(get_the_date('H:i:s'));
```

## Other

```
    $the_date = get_the_date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $a = explode(' ', $the_date);
    $date = $a[0];
    $time = $a[1];
```

## Other

```
$date = get_the_date();
$time = get_the_time();
     ?>
```

Comment: The second variant works as I need. Thank you.
first - VScode error: where are "(" and ";".
third - $time returns same as $date.